# Oracle 11g - parsing words of a column in a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update a CITY field. This is for Canada addresses, but I'm going to keep it simple for my issue. CITY fields contain only one word where the STATE field contains multiple words (usually no more than 3 words separated by a space.), but the majority of the STATE values contain two words separated by a space.

Example: CITY will show NEW and STATE will show YORK NY

Now I am trying to update CITY with it to show NEW YORK right now. Have not gotten to the part where I need to update the STATE as well. Baby steps I guess.

What I have:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET CITY = CITY || ' ' || SUBSTR(STATE, 1, INSTR(STATE, ' '))
WHERE SUBSTR(STATE, 1, INSTR(STATE, ' ')) IS NOT NULL;
```

When I just run :

```
SELECT CITY || ' ' || SUBSTR(STATE, 1, INSTR(STATE, ' '))
WHERE SUBSTR(STATE, 1, INSTR(STATE, ' ')) IS NOT NULL;
```

I get the first word of the STATE field, so it shows me I'm kind of on track.

Any info on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message you're getting should provide a clue.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that you have data incorrectly parsed already, and you want to correct it? That is, change it from CITY="New" and STATE="York NY" to CITY="New York" and STATE="NY"? Or are you saying something else?

Comment: @MJB - The data has been parsed incorrectly.

Comment: Hello @dolm77. I changed your title to reflect what you're trying to do. I believe you should use Oracle's regular expressions to get through, it should be very simple.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley - I was not using the concatenation operator. Thanks for the push.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to correct the data (though I and not 100% - if that is the case) then your code seems fine.

create table t1 (city varchar2(100), state varchar2(100))
insert into t1 values ('NEW','YORK NY')

update t1 set  city = city ||' '||SUBSTR(STATE, 1, INSTR(STATE, ' ')) 
WHERE SUBSTR(STATE, 1, INSTR(STATE, ' ')) IS NOT NULL;

Now city column : New York

select state ,SUBSTR(STATE, length(state) -1, INSTR(STATE, ' '))  from t1
WHERE SUBSTR(STATE, 1, INSTR(STATE, ' ')) IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Didnt see your comment til after I figured it out. Thanks for the input though.